# Calling Processor from Inside Bean

Tags: java, spring, groovy, apache-camel

New to Camel, so maybe I'm misunderstanding how processors and beans should interact. We have some logging to a database that we want to do throughout a camel route. The idea was to do this in a processor. However, we'd also like to do this logging from w/in the beans. Is that possible? I know I could pass it back as a return field from the bean...but it is already passing back a return.

A related question is how to pass that status, thinking it would be an exchange property or header.

Basically I want something along the lines of

processor

```
class EventStatusProcessor implements Processor {

    @Override
    void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {

        // do some stuff, thinking this will be a header
    }
}
```

route

```
from("direct:route1")
                .bean(doSomething, 'doSomething')
                .process(new EventStatusProcessor())
```

bean

```
@Component
@Slf4j
class DoSomething{
    String doSomething()

        //doing stuff

        new EventStatusProcessor().process()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass [`Exchange`](https://camel.apache.org/maven/current/camel-core/apidocs/org/apache/camel/Exchange.html) to method invoked with bean component too and set there headers/properties/body/whatever depending on your needs.

```
class DoSomething {
    @SuppressWarnings("unused") //called via Camel bean invocation
    public void doSomething(Exchange exchange){
        exchange.setProperty("propertyFromDoSomething", "Hello, I am property");
        exchange.getIn().setHeader("headerFromDoSomething", "Hi, I am header");
        exchange.getIn().setBody("It's me, body!");
    }
}

class EventStatusProcessor implements Processor {
    @Override
    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
        System.out.println(exchange.getIn().getHeader("headerFromDoSomething", String.class));
        System.out.println(exchange.getProperty("propertyFromDoSomething", String.class));
        System.out.println(exchange.getIn().getBody(String.class));
    }
}
```

---

If you really need to call processor **inside** bean, as you are writing in title, extract processor to `direct` route and then invoke it with [ProducerTemplate](http://camel.apache.org/producertemplate.html).

**RouteBuilder**

```
from("direct:log")
        .process(new EventStatusProcessor());
```

**DoSomething class**

```
public class DoSomething {
    @SuppressWarnings("unused") //called via Camel bean invocation
    public void doSomething(Exchange exchange){
        exchange.getContext().createProducerTemplate().sendBody("direct:log", "I am body and I will be passed to EventStatusProcessor");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, sorry for the delay. Been learning a lot and discussed this with a few people. They didn't so much like the idea of passing a bean to the exchange (seems like it is really a processor, masquerading as a bean :) ), but we can't think of another way :/

In the end, I think we're going to stick to doing this from the route.

So, that slightly changes my question. Right now each "log" takes two lines:
* setProperty('statusName', 'status')
* .process(statusProcessor)

we were hoping to do one,
.recordStatus("Started")

any way to do that? should this be a separate post?

Comment: Yes, ask a new question. In comments is not enough space for this. But I dont understant what you think with "pass bean to exchange", so if you are going to open new question, be detailed please.

Comment: ok, thanks. I was running into the limits of length in explaining that in the comments. so good advice. appreciate your time